# PyTorch running under WSL2 getting "Killed" for Out of memory even though I have a lot of memory left?

Tags: memory, pytorch, out-of-memory, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I'm on Windows 11, using WSL2 (Windows Subsystem for Linux). I recently upgraded my RAM from 32 GB to 64 GB.

While I can make my computer use more than 32 GB of RAM, WSL2 seems to be refusing to use more than 32 GB. For example, if I do

```
>>> import torch
>>> a = torch.randn(100000, 100000) # 40 GB tensor
```

Then I see the memory usage go up until it hit's 30-ish GB, at which point, I see "Killed", and the python process gets killed. Checking `dmesg`, it says that it killed the process because "Out of memory".

Any idea what the problem might be, or what the solution is?

Comment: Right.  WSL2 is a VM, so it's resources are limited.  Why not just dual boot LInux?

Answer (score 9):

According to [this blog post](https://joe.blog.freemansoft.com/2022/01/setting-your-memory-and-swap-for-wsl2.html), WSL2 is automatically configured to use 50% of the physical RAM of the machine.  You'll need to add a `memory=48GB` (or your preferred setting) to a `.wslconfig` file that is placed in your Windows home directory (`\Users\{username}\`).

```
[wsl2]
memory=48GB
```

After adding this file, shut down your distribution and wait at least [8 seconds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl-config) before restarting.

Assume that Windows 11 will need quite a bit of overhead to operate, so setting it to use the full 64 GB would cause the Windows OS to run out of memory.

Comment: I tried this, and I also needed to restart the host Windows machine before it would stop murdering the VM whenever it went over the original memory limit.

Comment: @DanielGiger try wsl --shutdown && wsl cat /proc/meminfo